# Magento 2.3.0 incorrect Email From

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3

When an order is placed in **Magento 2.3** It is sending sales email from `magemojo@domain.com` instead it should send from `info@domain.com` as configured from backend. I tried applying the patch but it's not working.

Comment: search for the email in your code from where it is coming also check to the configuration section at store level

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI Its bug of Magento 2.3.0